# Responder a preguntas donde no se requiere código

Tags: discusión

Mi duda surge a partir de esta pregunta:

- [Extraer caracteres de una cadena y guardarlos en otra variable usando Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/596111/16597)

El OP específica que:

> Por el momento no pido código porque quiero tratar de hacerlo por mi mismo, solo su asesoria de como podria hacerse el proceso y que funciones podría usar para extraer las cadenas de caracteres.

Si leo [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), dice:

> [..] Creemos que las mejores preguntas en Stack Overflow tienen siempre un poco de código **pero si tu pregunta es acerca de…**
>
> - **un problema específico de programación, o**
> - [...]

Entonces, ¿deberiamos dar una respuesta o dejar un comentario?

Comment: En mi opinión, es "respondible". Y se lo podría hacer eventualmente en pseudocódigo.

Comment: Pensándolo bien, en realidad la pregunta se puede resumir en **¿Cómo puedo separar la cadena `35 8/16` en un arreglo como `["35", "8/16"]`?** Solo que tiene ruido y aparenta ser una pregunta de las que no respondemos.

Comment: @Mateo sin mencionar que con simplemente buscar _"separa cadena en javascript"_ en un buscador te aparece la "respuesta". Desde mi punto de vista esta en un gris.

Comment: a pesar de ser respondible... sigue estando basada en opiniones ... cuantas formas distintas existen para llegar a la respuesta incluso puede ser duplicada de esta otra pregunta: [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/342202/buscar-un-caracter-en-una-cadena-de-texto-crear-array-y-dar-un-valor-aleatorio)